# How to create a ssh for more than one linux server?

Tags: ssh, webserver

updated*

I have two Linux servers CentOS 7 & Debian 6 running a vulnerable web app  inside virtual Box, my host OS is Kali Linux & connected to both VM'S with Host -only -adapter settings. i can successfully SSH to CentOS, but when i SSH to Debian it says Host verification failed, my question was how to ssh to debian without getting error or connect to more than one vm ?

" apologies for not providing enough info earlier" as requested i have the details

ssh_config

```
Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   -o CheckHostIP no 192.168.56.101
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking no
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com

#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
    NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost yes
```

sshd_config

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin without-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`enter code here`
```

Comment: connect using console and investigate the issue. If you are not able to authenticate with valid key or password, than there is no way to go by this channel (it is called secure). And please provide full error you get.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

- add `-o "CheckHostIP no"` option to ssh command line;
- add the following snipplet to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

> Host ip-address-of-your-VM
>
> CheckHostIP no

Update:

Did i get it right from your update, that the file you have in your `~/.ssh` directory is named `ssh_config`? If this is true, you did a mistake: it should be named just `config` (without `ssh_`)

In the config you posted you have a line that you obviously add:

```
#   -o CheckHostIP no 192.168.56.101
```

It should look completely different:

```
Host 192.168.56.101
CheckHostIP no
```

And preferably put these two lines at very end of you `config` file so the entry for your VM host derives all other settings you have set.

Comment: i did it but i don't know where i made mistake its still gives same error, here's my file       inside  ssh_config


#   -o CheckHostIP no 192.168.56.101

Comment: Could you update your question with the cut&paste copy of your config file, please use 'code sample' button to keep all formatting. Thank you

Comment: check question its updated